# Find function $f(x)$ whose expansion is $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}k^2x^k$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

I know the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is $$1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^k+\cdots$$

So taking the derivative of $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

And subsequently the expansion is (after taking derivative): $$1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+...+ kx^{(k-1)}$$

And multiplying by $x$: $$x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots+kx^k+\cdots$$

I can't seem to figure out how to work with knowing the above expansion and knowing I need to arrive at: $$x+2^2 x^2+3^2 x^3 +\cdots+k^2 x^k +\cdots$$

I thought it would be a matter of $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}$ or some form of squaring or adding a constant in there but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Simplify $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}k^2x^{k}$.

Differentiate and multiply the below expression by $x$ twice
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}x^k&=\frac{1}{1-x}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}kx^{k-1}&=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}kx^{k}&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=-\frac{1}{(1-x)}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}k^2x^{k-1}&=-\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}=\frac{x+1}{(1-x)^3}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}k^2x^{k}&=\frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Some trouble with the indexes, check the limits.

Comment: Sameer Thank you for explaining clearer (and Rafa for pointing out the indexes). It didn't intuitively become clear to me to differentiate and multiply by x twice. I understand it better now. Appreciate the step by step explanation!

Comment: @RafaBudría What about the index?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

Write $k^2=k(k-1)+k$, and use that
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k\ge 0}kx^{k-1}=\biggl(\frac 1{1-x}\biggr)'=\frac 1{(1-x)^2},\\
&\sum_{k\ge 0}k(k-1)x^{k-2}=\biggl(\frac 1{1-x}\biggr)''=\frac 2{(1-x)^3}.
\end{align}

Comment: The oooold good trick ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I'm afraid I'm confined to good old tricks under these circumstances ;o)

Comment: Nice "jeu de mots" !

Comment: @Bernard Great trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

FYI,

You can also check it at polylogarithm functions

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}k^2x^{k}=\operatorname{Li}_{-2}(x)=\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$